# An array for deleting a group of items in a list.DIT:

Tags: jquery

What I'm attempting to do is have their be an array of items that are checked be made for when the user clicks on the Delete Content Pages. I have an array with the name in the check boxes but I'm thinking my thinking is wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/UvdeC/

Edit:

```
$('.ask2').jConfirmAction( {  
     question : "Are you sure you want to delete all selected rows?",  
     questionClass: "question2", 
     onYes: function(evt){  
       contentpages(evt.target); 
     }  
} );

function contentpagesArray(whatsThis) {
    $('#delete').click(function () {
        var delOut = new Array();
        $('tbody')
            .children()
            .find('td>input[type="checkbox"]')
            .each(function ()
            {
                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                delOut.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });
        console.debug(delOut);
        alert(delOut);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with all of your other js files, this solution broke in practice (because I couldn't edit your files).  But a good example would be:

```
$('#delete').click(function ()
                   {
                        var delOut = new Array();
                        $('tbody')
                            .children()
                            .find('td>input[type="checkbox"]')
                            .each(function ()
                            {
                                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                                delOut.push($(this).attr('value'));
                            });
                        console.debug(delOut);
                        alert(delOut);
                    });
```

Instead of using click, I would patch this into the confirmation click for the popup dialogue you have.  This will generate an array, which can be used by jquery as data for your ajax post (just add the other values needed to the array).
Hope this helps (make sure not to use tbody for the main selector if you have more then one table as well).

Comment: I like it but I'm a little confused on where you said I need to put that.

Comment: So put everything from inside the click function (in the code above) before the ajax call that deletes the items.  You can then pass the delOut array in.  Do note, I used the value of the checkbox (which isn't set in your example).  So set that in your php code to a unique Identifier for each row.

Comment: Where do I have a id of delete?

Comment: So if you are using the row's id, when you echo out the checkbox html, put the id inside the value attribute, so `<input type="checkbox" value="IDHERE" />`

Comment: So what does contentpages function do?

Comment: @JeffDavidson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1682/discussion-between-mazzzzz-and-jeff)